# Find and Replace XML Attributes by Indexing - Python

Tags: python, xml, attributes, lxml, elementtree

I am attempting to find and replace XML attributes with new values based on indexing.  I can replace the attribute values if I hard code the attribute values themselves into my find/replace function, but I need to do so via indexing, specifically for the first two listed attributes with "text" values for both the <foo_1> and <foo_2> elements.  Below is the XML, along with the script I am using and the new values to be added to the XML and desired output:

The XML ("foo_bar.xml")

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Overlay>
    <foo_1>
        <bar key="value">text_1</bar>
        <bar key="value">text_2</bar>
        <bar key="value">text_3</bar>
    </foo_1>
    <foo_2>
        <bar key="value">text_4</bar>
        <bar key="value">text_5</bar>
        <bar key="value">text_6</bar>
    </foo_2>
</Overlay>
```

Script

```py
import lxml.etree as ET
xml = ET.parse("C:\\Users\\mdl518\\Desktop\\bar_foo.xml")
tree=xml.getroot()

new_val_1 = float(100/202)
new_val_2 = float(200/500)
new_val_3 = float(4/44)
new_val_4 = float(4/1000)

# Find and replace first and second "bar" subelement attribute values for each "foo" parent element
for elem in tree.getiterator():
    if elem.text:
        elem.text=elem.text.replace(text_1,new_val_1)
    if elem.text:
        elem.text=elem.text.replace(text_2,new_val_2)
    if elem.text:
        elem.text=elem.text.replace(text_4,new_val_3)
    if elem.text:
        elem.text=elem.text.replace(text_5,new_val_4)
    print(elem.text)
```

Desired result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Overlay
    <foo_1>
        <bar key="value">new_val_1</bar>
        <bar key="value">new_val_2</bar>
        <bar key="value">text</bar>
    </foo_1>
    <foo_2>
        <bar key="value">new_val_3</bar>
        <bar key="value">new_val_4</bar>
        <bar key="value">text</bar>
    </foo_2>
</Overlay>
```

Is there a convenient way to index the subelement attribute values and replace them with the desired values (i.e. "new_val_#") and write to XML? Any assistance is most appreciated!

Comment: Please show desired result as I am confused of your meaning of *attributes* since you do not show attempt of `elem.attrib` in code.

Comment: I do not see in desired result how *key* attribute is ever used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider elementwise loop, `zip`, on list of your needed values and `iterfind` generator. Run a nested loop for aligning sets of elements and values. Also there is no need to check `if elem.text` since every XML element has an underlying text node (empty or not). And if entire string contains `text` simply assign rather than `replace`. Do note: `zip` stops elementwise looping on shorter list:

```py
# LIST OF VALUES
new_vals = [float(100/202), float(200/500), float(4/44), float(4/1000)]

# SUBLIST OF VALUES BY 2 (ADJUST 2 FOR ANY OTHER NUMBER)
sub_new_vals = [new_vals[i:i+2]  for i in range(0, len(new_vals), 2)]

for nvs, el in zip(sub_new_vals, tree.iterfind('./*')):
    # Find and replace first and second attribute values
    for nv, elem in zip(nvs, el.iterfind('./*')):
        #elem.attrib["key"] = str(round(nv, 3))       # UPDATE ATTRIBUTE VALUE
        elem.text = str(round(nv, 3))                 # UPDATE ELEMENT TEXT
        print(elem.text)
                          
output = ET.tostring(tree, 
                     encoding="UTF-8",
                     method="xml", 
                     xml_declaration=True, 
                     pretty_print=True)
  
print(output.decode("utf-8"))
```

**Output**

```
0.495
0.4
0.091
0.004
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Overlay>
    <foo_1>
        <bar key="value">0.495</bar>
        <bar key="value">0.4</bar>
        <bar key="value">text_3</bar>
    </foo_1>
    <foo_2>
        <bar key="value">0.091</bar>
        <bar key="value">0.004</bar>
        <bar key="value">text_6</bar>
    </foo_2>
</Overlay>
```

Comment: Hey, @Parfait, thank you for your edits - It works pretty slick!  My apologies for doing so, but I actually updated my original question as to inquire about how to do this for two sets of elements/attributes.  Does the same logic apply?  Thanks again!!

Comment: Hey, @Parfait, I made one ( final) update to my original post to make the xml more well formed and more clearly pose the question at hand.  When I re-ran your edit, I get the following output:
```<Overlay>
             <foo_1>0.495<bar key="value">text_1</bar>
  <bar key="value">text_2</bar>
  <bar key="value">text_3</bar>
      </foo_1>
      <foo_2>0.4<bar key="value">text_4</bar>
  <bar key="value">text_5</bar>
  <bar key="value">text_6</bar>
      </foo_2>
      </Overlay>```.  The 0.495 and 0.4 values need to be where 'text_1' and 'text_4' are, but it's getting closer!

Comment: Thank you, @Parfait, the updated nested loop works beautifully!  I'll confirm this as the correct solution, much appreciated!! :)